# How do I stop my PC's `LongPathsEnabled` registry setting from being reset to zero?

Tags: windows, configuration-management

I have enabled long file paths in Windows 11, by using regedit to set the `LongPathsEnabled` registry value to `1`, in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`.

This has worked fine for years, but last week the `LongPathsEnabled` setting has been repeatedly reset to `0`.

Each time I set it to `1`, within a day or two it set to `0`.

I have tried to fix this by using `gpedit.msc` to set the "Enable Win32 long paths" setting to "Enabled" in the Local Computer Policy (under `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Filesystem`), but this has not helped.

How can I stop the `LongPathsEnabled` registry value from being set to zero?

How can I find out what is setting it?

My company controls policy settings on my machine, but is not setting this. How can I detect if they are setting it?

Comment: `My company has some control of policy settings on my machine` did you ask? How about the output of `gpresult /h file.html`?

Comment: **My company has some control of policy settings on my machine, could that be affecting it?** - Yes.

Comment: Updated to qualify that my company is not deliberately resetting it, and to ask if there is a way to see if something they are doing is accidentally causing it to be reset.

Comment: I couldn't see any clues from running `gpresult /h file.html'.

Comment: offtopic, ask your it company to force the behavior

Answer (score 2):

If the registry key is changed, it must be done by some process or thread. I would suggest tracing the key with Process Monitor and see if you can find out what changes it. So before you can stop it you need to know what changes it.

You could also use another tool from Sysinternals (now for years) and that's Sysmon, this run as a Windows Service and with a custom xml you can audit the changes on the system in a more detailed way.

A custom xml for sysmon, auditing that key, could look like this

```
<Sysmon schemaversion="4.22">
  <RegistryEvent>
    <TargetObject condition="end with">\LongPathsEnabled</TargetObject>
  </RegistryEvent>
</Sysmon>
```

For an automated install of sysmon i definitely recommend this github repo

```
https://github.com/simeononsecurity/Automate-Sysmon
```

There is already an custom xml in there, but you might need to add a rule for the LongPathsEnabled in that xml
https://github.com/simeononsecurity/Automate-Sysmon/blob/main/Files/sysmonconfig-export.xml

---

Uninstall Lenovo Client Software

[image: Lenovo uninstall]

Comment: Thanks. I've set up Process Monitor to track changes to the registry key, and will hopefully find something soon.

Comment: Using this technique on my laptop, I discovered that the "Universal Device Client Service" created by Lenovo was resetting this flag in the registry. That service appears to be for some remote management functionality that I don't need, so I've disabled that service to stop it happening.
The executable file that changed it is located at `C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\Lenovo\udc\Service\UDClientService.exe` on my machine.

Comment: I also found a way to uninstall it. You might also want to debloat it installing a clean windows image without all the Lenovo software

Comment: @X-Cubed: `"Universal Device Client Service" created by Lenovo was resetting this flag in the registry. That service appears to be for some remote management functionality that I don't need` https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/ps500567-lenovo-udc-vulnerability *Uncontrolled search path vulnerabilities were reported in the Lenovo Universal Device Client (UDC) that could allow an attacker with local access to execute code with elevated privileges.*

Answer (score 0):

This started happening to me a few weeks ago after a Windows 11 update.

Apparently setting it in the "Local Group Policy Editor" fixes it for me (the setting in regedit is always reset, but the group policy is maintained and the system seems to be able to write long files).

i.e.: In `gpedit.msc`, on `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `System` > `Filesystem` -- `Enable win32 long paths`.

Note: in my case there's no company which has any control over it and I started seeing it after a Windows 11 update (my suspicion is that Microsoft introduced a bug...).

Comment: Hmmm. I have the same Local Computer Policy set, but it does not fix the problem for me. I'm still seeing failures to create files with long paths until I reset the Registry setting.